# IntelIJ does not see the right path to the driver

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I know that that may be a silly question but I can not solve this problem by my own.
I try to learn automatic testing in Java but when I run my test IntelIJ shows me:
`"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist: C:\Users\grzeg\IdeaProjects\A\"C:\Users\grzeg\Desktop\Drivers\chromedriver.exe`"
Well,the path to the driver I have in a file "configuration.properties" which includes : "chrome.driver.location = "C:/Users/grzeg/Desktop/Drivers/chromedriver.exe".
In my project I get this path by calling this method:

```
public static String getChromeWebDriverLocation(){

  return ConfigurationProperties.getProperties().getProperty("chrome.driver.location");
}
```

Then I call this method in other classes and finally I call this method in my test case.
As You see I dont duplicate the path in my file but everytime I try to run the test I see the result with whole path to the driver after "/IdeaProjects/A/". I know that it is an error bot I can not fix it.

Comment: It looks like you're missing or have one too many quotation marks (`"`) in `"chrome.driver.location = "C:/Users/grzeg/Desktop/Drivers/chromedriver.exe"`, try removing the first or adding one after, (i.e. `"chrome.driver.location" = "C:/Users/grzeg/Desktop/Drivers/chromedriver.exe"`)

Answer (score 1):

This is old way of doing,
Download driver, store it in one location, setting driver path and initializing.

follow this website, this is really helpful.

1. include dependency in pom.xml
2. WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonny Henly was saying you have to many quotes I would suggest trying to put a \ next to the quotes you want to keep besides the first and last ones example

```
"My professor said \"you must do all your homework\" so unfortunately I have to do it"
```